# Counting the rows in a data frame that satisfy some criteria and grouping them by the unique values in the first column of the data frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data with househould id's, gender and age as follows:

```
mydata <- 

structure(list(ID_HH = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5), 
                           GENDER = c(1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1), 
                           AGE = c(50,45,3,15,25,5,32,30,10,28,64,16)), 
                      .Names = c("ID", "GENDER", "AGE"), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

   mydata

#  HH_ID GENDER AGE
# 1  1    1    50
# 2  1    2    45
# 3  1    1    3
# 4  1    1    15
# 5  2    1    25
# 6  2    2    5
# 7  3    2    32
# 8  3    1    30
# 9  3    2    10
# 10 4    2    28
# 11 5    1    64
# 12 5    1    16
```

I have another dataframe, lets call it 'output', that has only the unique HH_ID values and some other columns next to it. What i would like to do is to add new columns to this data frame that shows:

- "the number of adult females (Gender=2 && Age=18)",
- "the number of adult males (Gender=1 && Age=18)",
- "the number of school children (6-18)" (Num_Sch), and
- "the number of preschpol children (0-6)"(Num_PreSch)

for each household. So 'output' should look like that:

```
    #  HH_ID Col1 Col2 ... Num_Fem Num_Male Num_PreSch Num_Sch
# 1  1    ..              1       1         1        1 
# 2  2    ..              0       1         1        0 
# 3  3    ..              1       1         0        1
# 4  4    ..              1       0         0        0
# 5  5    ..              0       1         0        1
```

I tried many different functions and packages but nothing could achieve exactly what I want. I would appreciate any help or comment.

Comment: I'm guessing you actually mean to count adults as `Age >= 18`, not `Age = 18`?

Comment: Also, what have you tried that got you the closest to what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already thinking about this in a way that translates well to logical statements (e.g. is this person female and 18 or over), so I'd do it with a series of logical vectors, utilizing the fact that because true/false translates to 1/0, you can sum them.

Set up the different categories and create logical columns for each.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  mutate(adult_female = (GENDER == 2 & AGE >= 18),
         adult_male = (GENDER == 1 & AGE >= 18),
         school = between(AGE, 6, 18),
         preschool = between(AGE, 0, 6))
#>    ID GENDER AGE adult_female adult_male school preschool
#> 1   1      1  50        FALSE       TRUE  FALSE     FALSE
#> 2   1      2  45         TRUE      FALSE  FALSE     FALSE
#> 3   1      1   3        FALSE      FALSE  FALSE      TRUE
#> 4   1      1  15        FALSE      FALSE   TRUE     FALSE
#> 5   2      1  25        FALSE       TRUE  FALSE     FALSE
#> 6   2      2   5        FALSE      FALSE  FALSE      TRUE
#> 7   3      2  32         TRUE      FALSE  FALSE     FALSE
#> 8   3      1  30        FALSE       TRUE  FALSE     FALSE
#> 9   3      2  10        FALSE      FALSE   TRUE     FALSE
#> 10  4      2  28         TRUE      FALSE  FALSE     FALSE
#> 11  5      1  64        FALSE       TRUE  FALSE     FALSE
#> 12  5      1  16        FALSE      FALSE   TRUE     FALSE
```

Then you can group by household and sum all the columns of the type logical.

```r
mydata %>%
  mutate(adult_female = (GENDER == 2 & AGE >= 18),
         adult_male = (GENDER == 1 & AGE >= 18),
         school = between(AGE, 6, 18),
         preschool = between(AGE, 0, 6)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_if(is.logical, sum)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>      ID adult_female adult_male school preschool
#>   <dbl>        <int>      <int>  <int>     <int>
#> 1     1            1          1      1         1
#> 2     2            0          1      0         1
#> 3     3            1          1      1         0
#> 4     4            1          0      0         0
#> 5     5            0          1      1         0
```

One issue that I'll let you handle: the function `between` is inclusive of its endpoints. You've described preschool as ages 0 to 6, and school-aged as ages 6 to 18. That means 6 year olds are counted in both. You probably want to adjust those endpoints, which shouldn't be too hard since it seems you're working with age as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a fancy way to do that, but you can simply do it using a `for` loop, as follows:

```
mydata  <- as.data.frame(mydata)
Num_Fem <- Num_Male <- Num_PreSch <- Num_Sch <- c()

for(ID_HH in output$ID_HH){
  curr_HH    <- mydata[mydata$ID_HH == ID_HH,]

  Num_Fem    <- c(Num_Fem,    nrow(curr_HH[curr_HH$GENDER==2 & curr_HH$AGE>=18,]))
  Num_Male   <- c(Num_Male,   nrow(curr_HH[curr_HH$GENDER==1 & curr_HH$AGE>=18,]))
  Num_PreSch <- c(Num_PreSch, nrow(curr_HH[curr_HH$AGE<6,]))
  Num_Sch    <- c(Num_Sch,    nrow(curr_HH[curr_HH$AGE>=6 & curr_HH$AGE<18,]))
}

output <- cbind(output, data.frame(Num_Fem, Num_Male, Num_PreSch, Num_Sch))
```

It will give you your expected results:

```
    #  HH_ID Col1 Col2 ... Num_Fem Num_Male Num_PreSch Num_Sch
# 1        1   ..   ..           1        1         1        1 
# 2        2   ..   ..           0        1         1        0 
# 3        3   ..   ..           1        1         0        1
# 4        4   ..   ..           1        0         0        0
# 5        5   ..   ..           0        1         0        1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. I was hoping to avoid using a for loop actually, but i forgot to mention it in the question.